# Informix - Create table with function weekday

Tags: sql, informix, create-table, weekday

I'm trying to create a table on Informix (11.70). I want to add the function WEEKDAY to a datetime value on the CREATE clause, so that I can automatically get an integer returned when inserting data.

For example.

```
     CREATE TABLE orders (

     order_num serial
     order_date datetime year to second
     order_weekday datetime year to second
     )
```

I've tried the following and I get syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (

     order_num serial
     order_date datetime year to second
     order_weekday WEEKDAY(datetime) year to second
     )
```

Also this

```
CREATE TABLE orders (

     order_num serial
     order_date datetime year to second
     WEEKDAY(order_weekday) datetime year to second
     )
```

Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is probably using FOR EACH ROW [triggers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0584.htm) which assign to the weekday column on INSERT and UPDATE given the value in the Order-Date column.

As [RET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14750/ret) notes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35190775/), it is often best not to store derived data, especially not such readily derivable data as the weekday.

However, assuming you need to do so, then your trigger would look like:

```
BEGIN WORK;
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_num SERIAL NOT NULL,
    order_date DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    order_weekday INTEGER CHECK (order_weekday BETWEEN 0 AND 6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES(0, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, WEEKDAY(MOD(WEEKDAY(TODAY) + 3, 7)));
SELECT *, WEEKDAY(order_date) AS calc_weekday FROM orders;
```

> ```
> order_num       order_date      order_weekday   calc_weekday
> SERIAL  DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND INTEGER SMALLINT
> 1       2016-02-04 23:21:36     0       4
> ```

```
CREATE TRIGGER i_orders INSERT ON orders
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
    (
        UPDATE orders
           SET order_weekday = WEEKDAY(NEW.order_date)
         WHERE order_num = NEW.order_num
    );
CREATE TRIGGER u_orders UPDATE OF order_date ON orders
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
    (
        UPDATE orders
           SET order_weekday = WEEKDAY(NEW.order_date)
         WHERE order_num = NEW.order_num
    );
INSERT INTO orders(order_num, order_date) VALUES(0, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND);
SELECT *, WEEKDAY(order_date) AS calc_weekday FROM orders;
```

> ```
> order_num       order_date      order_weekday   calc_weekday
> SERIAL  DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND INTEGER SMALLINT
> 1       2016-02-04 23:21:36     0       4
> 2       2016-02-04 23:21:36     4       4
> ```

```
UPDATE orders
   SET order_date = order_date - 10 UNITS DAY
 WHERE order_weekday != WEEKDAY(order_date);
SELECT *, WEEKDAY(order_date) AS calc_weekday FROM orders;
```

> ```
> order_num       order_date      order_weekday   calc_weekday
> SERIAL  DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND INTEGER SMALLINT
> 1       2016-01-25 23:21:36     1       1
> 2       2016-02-04 23:21:36     4       4
> ```

```
ROLLBACK WORK;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? It is a fundamental principle of RDBMS normalisation that you should not store a value that can be derived from another existing field. You can calculate `WEEKDAY(order_date)` any time you need it at virtually no cost.

However, if you really want to do this, what you need to do is write an *INSERT TRIGGER*, as @JonathanLeffer suggested whilst I was writing this.

You might also want to clarify what you mean by "get an integer returned". The database returns something on a successful `INSERT`, but you cannot override that arbitrarily. If you really want to do that, you need to write a PROCEDURE to handle inserting the record to the `orders` table and returning the value you require.